# DND (Do not disturb) feature for notifications like email,sms etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, apache-kafka, architecture

I have microservices created for sending multiple notifications like email,sms etc which are consuming notifications from kafka. I want user preference like DND to be considered like user should not receive notifications in the DND period specified.

How can I acheive this DND feature as kafka will constantly keep sending me messages with a timestamp(date and time to send the message) at what time notification should be triggered and confirm that user wont receive these notifications in the DND period subscribed?

Can I get some help with this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully experienced in Kafka, but I have some knowledge on the microservice architecture and message queue.

Since the microservices are consuming the tasks from the Queue or Kafka, the DND can be implemented in the consuming microservice. It may need to execute additional task to check if User is in DND and then send the notification.

However, the microservice is task specific, it will be better it just send the notification, so maybe the application/microservice which posts tasks to Kafka can be modified.

Microservice A -> Kafka -> Notification microservice (B)

Microservice A can check the DND before passing to Kafka or

Microservice A can attach the user DND time period info to Kafka along with other notification details . Now when B receives/consumes from Kafka, it checks if it is within DND period and will simply neglect it, otherwise.

----Added after the first comment----

I thought that the notifications within the DND can be discarded.
Here is what we can do to send notification later.

---- Answer is based on the above architecture----

**To send the notification later without discarding it**, you can create another local queue (an array or any feasible Data Structure) or use in-memory queue like Redis.

Now based on what I suggested earlier, now instead of discarding the notification falling in DND, we can avoid sending & put this in this newly created queue.

Microservice B can have a scheduler, lets say every 15 minutes.

Also, assuming as I described earlier, a notification will have a DND parameter (since this queue contains notifications that were skipped, the actual time to send is no longer needed or valid)

Now every 15 minute (or whatever time is set), the Microservice B can check the contents of this queue & send the notifications only if it falls outside of DND, and finally remove it from the queue.

If the time is still in DND we keep the notification in the queue without removing it, so it will again picked up for processing 15 minutes (the time set up) later.

Lastly, if B is already overloaded, we can create another simple microservice that will just check this new queue  every 15 minutes if the notification is within DND and pass it to Microservice B to send the actual notification.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer but if my message is in DND I would want that message should be sent and not discarded. I am flexible to keep the DND logic anywhere which is not a major concern for me but I need some help with logic as to how can i send the message which has arrived in Users DND period to be sent later?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it was my mistake that I thought we can discard the notification if within DND. I have updated the answer to now send notifications later, instead of discarding it.

Comment: In the updated answer, I have mentioned scheduler to schedule every 15 minutes. One scheduler is available in npm named "cron" , should work in production as well.

Comment: Microservice B cannot specifically pick messages from queue there is no such possibily as its a queue working as FIFO.Have any other alternate to this?

Comment: Ah, actually, I was trying to provide the high level logic. If you use a queue (FIFO) , check every element i.e. remove from the queue one by one. Now process it if outside DND, else keep it an array locally in Microservice B. Now, after the queue is empty, you need to put array contents of unprocessed notifications back in the queue which will again be processed 15 minutes later. As I told you, it's the idea . You can actually use any Data Structure . Just process, check DND and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your messages based on your DND logic after you consume the messages from your notification topic. Post that you can write it back to another Kafka topic say `dnd-notifications` and read it from there. Since Kafka is used for `exactly-once` delivery, you will have to push your dnd messages to a new topic.

**Edit-26-Sept:**

In the hind sight, putting your dnd-notifications into a separate topic wouldnt work in case like '"What if the dnd period for a user last for more than 7-days"'. Kafka has by-default ,message retention time of 7 days(which you can increase) but kafka is not meant for storage.

What you need to do is involve a database and have 2 microservice. One microservice will be a consumer microservice that will read kafka and write messages to a table in database with a flag (i.e. `is_read`, true if the message was already pushed to user and read). By default, `is_read` will be false for any new message.

The second microservice will be the one that will actually push the notifications out taking into consideration user dnd-configuration. It should read all the unread message table from database, check the user dnd-config and then push to the user. This second service can poll the db at regular time and send out the unread messages.[image]

Comment: But what after pushing it to dnd-notifications how will my consumer microservice understand what time the message is supposed to be triggered at and what if the messages received are still in the dnd period and should not be triggered?